# Simple Combobox in Winforms - Firing twice (Use mouse to expand combobox and select a item using keyboard)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

Consider a very basic form with a simple combo box

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("test1");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("test2");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("test3");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, args) => 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Combo box changed!");
        };
    }
}
```

I have even changed the eventhandler to the below code. (Based on the linked question. Still the same problem)

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += (o, args) => //or even `Textchanged` event too
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Combo box changed!");
            };
```

Expand the dropdown using `mouse` and select any item using `keyboard`.

The combo-box fires twice (The message box appears twice)

Any ideas why?

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` instead of message boxes for debug purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching Unselecting All in ListView -- SelectedIndexChanged Firing Twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740756/catching-unselecting-all-in-listview-selectedindexchanged-firing-twice)

Comment: Do you have any other code that initialized this event? i.e., in the designer.cs

Comment: @allentranks: Nope. This is the only code that I have written. The designer is untouched

Comment: @Sayse: Actually the linked question doesn't seem to solve my issue. Even after using `ItemSelectionChanged` the event still fires twice

Comment: Replace that `MessageBox.Show` with `Console.WriteLine` and check. It fires only once. `MessageBox` is doing something that causes it to be raised twice.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. - Searching for "SelectedValueChanged fires twice" returns lots of results.. Can I ask what it is that you are actually doing with the combobox?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel definitely fires twice, click on expander, type 'test3', hit 'enter', two events fire

Comment: @paul Read my comment again. With messagebox, it fires twice but if you add `Console.WriteLine`, It will be fired only once.

Comment: @Sayse: Pretty simple. Just wanna call a function (which inturn updates a text on a label). But problem is whenever I expand the combobox using a mouse and choose an item using keyboard, it fires twice

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Sorry. But how to check the items written in `console.writeline` ? Winforms doesn't have a console.writeline window ?

Comment: You need to look at the output in output window of visual studio, or change the project to console application; console will appear.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel not on my pc, `Debug.Print`, `Console.WriteLine`, `MessageBox` all show twice

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I did that.. As Paul says, they are fired twice

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. - Have you tried using the `TextChanged` event instead?

Comment: @Sayse: Still firing twice.. `Expand using mouse. Choose an item using keyboard`.. fires twice even with `TextChanged`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Hey sriram, do you know if this is a bug ? Or am I doing wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Trust me it fires only once for me. Windows 8, .Net 4.0, Vs 2012. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Even with a messageBox in place ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel once if you click, once if you use the keyboard up down arrows, twice if you type 'test3' and hit the 'enter' key

Comment: @paul: Exactly. the same issue. Do you think this is an issue with `winforms` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Make sure `you expand the dropdown with a mouse` and `using up/down keys in keyboard, select an item` . Then the item is fired twice

Comment: Done everything you said. With MessageBox, it is called twice as I already said. But when I replace it with Console.WriteLine, it is called only once. Not sure what's going on with you. I tried as you said "typed test3 and press enter" it fired only once.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: In real time code, it is not a message box. I am performing a complex logic within a method that is fired on `SelectedIndexChanged`. So, this method is called twice. And this is why i am worried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug with the underlying framework.

So, I managed to get a work around of the issue.

Here's how:

1. Have a private variable (preferably)  which can store the value of the selected item in the combo-box
2. Next time, compare it with the current selection in the combo-box. If they are same, just return.